# If function to perform function upon matching two user ids from different lists?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I am looking for some help adding to my current code, I'm have two lists of usernames the lists would look like this:

```
Fishermen A:

George
Tom
Joel
Tom
Lance


Fishermen B:

George
Tom
Tom
```

What I want to be able to do is essentially if a username appears in Fisherman A list and Fisherman B list, then count the number of times it appears in both lists. So in this instance the code would list Tom 4 times and George times 2,  Otherwise do nothing. I am a relative novice with coding, so any comments and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the answer Tom 4 and George 2?

Comment: please show exactly what you want the output to be.

Comment: Soory guys, yes Tom 4 and George 2 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fishermanA = ['George', 'Tom', 'Joel', 'Tom', 'Lance']
fishermanB = ['George', 'Tom', 'Tom']
a_set = set(fishermanA)
b_set = set(fishermanB)
inter = a_set.intersection(b_set)
for i in inter:
    print(i, fishermanA.count(i) + fishermanB.count(i))


Output:
('George', 2)
('Tom', 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a job for [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1 = ['George', 'Tom', 'Joel', 'Tom', 'Lance']
>>> l2 = ['George', 'Tom', 'Tom']
>>> Counter(filter((set(l1) & set(l2)).__contains__, l1 + l2))
Counter({'Tom': 4, 'George': 2})
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fmenA = [
    "George",
    "Tom",
    "Joel",
    "Tom",
    "Lance",
]

fmenB = [
    "George",
    "Tom",
    "Tom",
]

countsA = defaultdict(int)
countsB = defaultdict(int) 

for name in fmenA:
    countsA[name] += 1

for name in fmenB:
    countsB[name] += 1

print {
         name: countsA[name] + countsB[name] 
         for name in countsA if name in countsB
      }


--output:--
{'George': 2, 'Tom': 4}



#The following data is highly skewed against count()

print len(string.printable)   #-->100

fmenA = list(string.printable)[:10]
fmenB = list(string.printable)[:10]
--------------------------------------
2.14819002151   defaultdict
1.860476017     count()
3.48084497452   Counter_arshajii
5.76169896126   Counter_jpmc26



fmenA = list(string.printable)[:20]
fmenB = list(string.printable)[:20]
--------------------------------------
3.87321305275    defaultdict
4.63102507591    count()
5.21796107292    Counter_arshajii
8.44607114792    Counter_jpmc26


fmenA = list(string.printable)[:40]
fmenB = list(string.printable)[:40]
--------------------------------------
7.59739494324         defaultdict
13.643941879272461    count()
9.3110909462          Counter_arshajii
15.3523819447         Counter_jpmc26



fmenA = list(string.printable)
fmenB = list(string.printable)
-------------------------------
18.7256119251    defaultdict
80.9080910683    count()
22.0006680489    Counter_arshajii
37.6448471546    Counter_jpmc26



import timeit

setup ="""
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
import string

fmenA = list(string.printable) 
fmenB = list(string.printable) 
"""

s1 = """
countsA = defaultdict(int)
countsB = defaultdict(int) 

for name in fmenA:
    countsA[name] += 1

for name in fmenB:
    countsB[name] += 1

{
    name: (countsA[name] + countsB[name]) 
    for name in countsA if name in countsB
}

"""

s2 = """
a_set = set(fmenA)
b_set = set(fmenB)
inter = a_set.intersection(b_set)

{
    name: fmenA.count(name) + fmenB.count(name) 
    for name in inter
}
"""

s3 = """
Counter(filter((set(fmenA) & set(fmenB)).__contains__, fmenA + fmenB))
"""

s4 = """
a = Counter(fmenA)
b = Counter(fmenB)
{k: a[k] + b[k] for k in a if a[k] > 0 and b[k] > 0}
"""

t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s1, setup=setup)
print(t.timeit(number=100000))
t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s2, setup=setup)
print(t.timeit(number=100000))
t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s3, setup=setup)
print(t.timeit(number=100000))
t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s4, setup=setup)
print(t.timeit(number=100000))
```

Comment: Generating the intersection set could be replaced with just using the keys from one count list and an `if` condition on the other count list inside the loop.

Comment: In Python 2.7, `countsA.keys() & countsB.keys()` generates an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the differences between 2.x and 3.x.  The print() statements should have been a dead give away. I added some test results for you.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the fact the OP tagged the question for Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes.....................

Answer (score 2):

I agree with arshaji that `Counter` is the way to go, but it seems to me that creating extra `set`s and accessing a magic method directly is unnecessary.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1 = ['George', 'Tom', 'Joel', 'Tom', 'Lance']
>>> l2 = ['George', 'Tom', 'Tom']
>>> a = Counter(l1)
>>> b = Counter(l2)
>>> counts = {k: a[k] + b[k] for k in a if a[k] > 0 and b[k] > 0}
>>> counts
{'George': 2, 'Tom': 4}
>>> for k in counts:
...     print str(k) + ': ' + str(counts[k])
...
George: 2
Tom: 4
```

Note that it's fine that we only iterate over the keys in one `Counter`. The key has to be in both lists for us to care about it, so if it's in both lists, it will be in the `Counter` we iterate over.

The advantage over Ankur Ankan's solution is efficiency for large lists. Ankur Ankan's solution iterates over both entire lists for **each common element**. The `Counter` only iterates over each list once and then over one `Counter`. For large lists and a large number of common elements, the performance difference will be very large. For small lists, the performance hit will be negligible.

Comment: "The advantage over Ankur Ankan's solution is efficiency for large lists."  Both the Counter solutions are terribly inefficient, and my tests show that yours is the slowest of them all--for any list size. I used the original lists and the original lists multiplied by 1000.    Do you mind posting your tests?

Comment: Hm. I was under the impression that `Counter` is generated at order `O(n)` and looks up at `O(1)` (hash table), but I suppose my assumption is wrong if your tests show otherwise. What happens if we convert the `Counter`s to `dict`s: `a = dict(Counter(l1))`? We should also try a pair of lists with a large number of distinct common elements as that provides a major performance impact as well (hence the "each common element" part).

Comment: With two lists ["Tom"] and ["Tom", "Tom"], your solution does not perform significantly better than the other Counter solution as the lists get larger (2->20,000), but the Counter solutions are both woeful--and I gave you the imports for free.  The count() solution is 20 times faster.  defaultdict is twice as fast with the largest lists.

Comment: defaultdict is actually 3-4 times as fast over the range of sizes.

Comment: I'm not clear what point you're trying to make; I said was that my assumptions must be wrong and made a pair of suggestions. Based on your testing, I'm not sure what the order of performance of my solution is, but Ankur Ankan's solution should at best have order `O((n+c)(a+b))` where `n` is the number of distinct common elements, `a` and `b` are the list lengths, and `c` is a constant (that gets multiplied by the list lengths) to account for generating the intersection set. (`c` is probably 1 or 2.) You're not increasing `n`, which has the largest impact.

Comment: I'm running some more tests with more distinct elements.